# Custom navigation drawer for settings

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to create `navigation drawer` for settings like in the `viber`? As default `nd` just has menu elements. How to add my own `view` elements like `checkbox`, `edit text`...Is `viber` use some modified `navigation drawer` or is it some lib or `fragment`?[image]

Comment: Of course, it's possible to make. But why do u not use a simple activity? You can style it like the settings screen.

Comment: A drawer in a `DrawerLayout` can be pretty much any `View` (or `ViewGroup`) you want. It doesn't have to be a `NavigationView`.

Comment: But if you want `PreferenceActivity` then you should understand that it extends a `Activity` (maybe not directly but extends). So, it has the root view that you can get to manipulate of child views and add a custom.

Comment: I liked this concept. And I want to try to use it.

Comment: As variant you can write own/override exisiting `DrawerLayout` to you could attach a listener for the root view motion events. Or override an activity to it inflates view from xml in the needed view.

Comment: [This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/777f5b2/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java) can be helpful for you